Signing documents in bulk (Google Docs) using Apps Script
I'd like to create a script to sign some Google Docs in bulk. My first idea was to store a Google drawing with the signature in my drive, and then insert it in the docs.
Any better idea than this?
Thank you!
For now I didn't code anything as I'm not convinced of my Google Drawing idea

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

No need to apologize! My question was not super clear. I'm generating a bunch of Google Docs based on a template, and I would like to be able afteward to sign some of them from my spreadsheet. I would check the rows with the documents I want to sign, and then the script would insert a signature in those.

Thank you for replying. I understand that you want to insert a sign to multiple Google Documents. But, unfortunately, I cannot imagine your situation. So, in order to correctly understand your expected result, I asked about the sample input and output situations you expect. By the way, I cannot understand I would check the rows with the documents I want to sign, and then the script would insert a signature in those..

This put an image a the bottom of a document.
function signature() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.openById(gobj.globals.testdocid);
  let body = doc.getBody();
  let file = DriveApp.getFileById(gobj.globals.coopersigid).getBlob();//file was a jpg of a signature
  body.appendImage(file);
}

